# Application not configured for billing through Google Play error

Tags: android, kotlin, revenuecat

I have the following code that allows people to purchase subscriptions in android/kotlin. However, when people click to purchase an annual subscription sometimes they get the error `Application not configured for billing through Google Play`

Sometimes I get the error "Error retrieving from the server"

Here's the code https://gist.github.com/naissa12/2e52e4ac40c1f7143b44e92923913f87

I'm using RevenueCats SDK

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.0'